# Combining Fields In MySQL Query

Tags: mysql

I have three InnoDB mysql tables.  One has a list of books, with fields for book_id, name, and the link to the item.  The other is a table of authors, that include author_id, first name, and last name, and the last table is an index of books to author.  Some works have more than one author.

I am trying to write a query that would pull all books, and in the author field show all authors for a given title. For example, if I wanted a list of books, the query would return the book id, book name, a link to where I can download it, and the name of all authors for the book.  Assuming there are 2 or more authors, how can I get all author names into one field?

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT b.book_id, book_title, link_src, CONCAT(a.firstname, ' ',a.lastname) AS author from books AS b
JOIN author_to_books AS atb ON b.book_id = atb.book_id
JOIN authors AS a ON atb.author_id = a.author_id
```

This gives me two separate rows for the same book.  For example, if Test Book 1 has Joe Public and John Smith as authors, I get two rows for the same book id.  I would like just one row with both of the authors in the author field.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) for this.

Quick example:

```
SELECT b.book_id, book_title, link_src, 
 GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(a.firstname, ' ',a.lastname)) AS author 
FROM books AS b
JOIN author_to_books AS atb ON b.book_id = atb.book_id
JOIN authors AS a ON atb.author_id = a.author_id
GROUP BY book_id
```

But usually you'd be better of doing this in your application code (since afterwards, you'll going to want to make the 'author' a clickable link too, etcetera).

Answer (score 0):

See the [GROUP_CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function.

```
SELECT b.book_id, b.book_title, b.link_src, 
  GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT(a.firstname, ' ',a.lastname) ) AS authors 
FROM books AS b
JOIN author_to_books AS atb ON b.book_id = atb.book_id
JOIN authors AS a ON atb.author_id = a.author_id
GROUP BY b.book_id
```